# Select subset of dataframe using condition on multi index

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by, multi-index

All,

I have a dataframe in the following format:

`ind   date         value1    value2
 x1    23-04-2018   1.3       7.2
 x1    03-05-2018   4.6       3.5
 x2    04-04-2018   2.0       8.5`

**ind** and **date** are the indices. If there are multiple rows for one value of **ind** I only want to keep the latest date.

So, in my example the preferred result is:

`ind   date         value1    value2
 x1    03-05-2018   4.6       3.5
 x2    04-04-2018   2.0       8.5`

The date column is in datetime format, so finding the max date within groups could work. But is it possible to use such a condition, for example in combination with a groupby (like GROUPBY and HAVING in SQL). Or is there a better method?

Does anyone have a solution or tips?

Edit: I slightly changed my example. Multiple rows are not necessarily duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sort_index and drop duplicates.

Where df has no indexes at first:

```
print(df)

  ind       date  value1  value2
0  x1 2018-04-23     1.3     7.2
1  x1 2018-03-05     1.3     7.2
2  x2 2018-04-04     2.0     8.5

df.set_index(['ind','date']).sort_index(level=[1], ascending=[False]).drop_duplicates()
```

Or as @piRSquare states:

```
df.set_index(['ind','date']).sort_index(level=[1]).drop_duplicates(keep='last')
```

Output:

```
                value1  value2
ind date                      
x1  2018-04-23     1.3     7.2
x2  2018-04-04     2.0     8.5
```

Comment: Could skip the ascending arg and use `keep='last'`.  Like the avatar change.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you.  I am feeling some school spirit today.

Comment: Thanks! This works for now. Rows are not necessarily duplicates, so it would be nice to have a solution for these situations too. Sorry for not giving a clear example

Comment: @Rob pass the column over which you want to evaluate duplicity.  `drop_duplicates('ind')`

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat verbose method that requires no sorting:

```
# Gets the row indices as list of lists
idx = df.reset_index('date', drop=False) \
    .groupby('ind', sort=False)['date'] \
    .max() \
    .iteritems()

df.loc(axis=0)[list(idx)]
```

This relies on the order of `['idx', 'date']` in `df`.